# Dynamically created select box not accepting option added by function

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have a short bit of code here that connects to a DB called karaoke and populates a select box. I just want to be able to add a select box option at index 0 that says something like "Please Select". I've tried multiple ways to do this in PHP, HTML, and Javascript, but haven't found a solution that I need. So far this code shows 0 errors in the Chrome debugger, but doesn't act as I expect. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <html>
  <head>
  <title>Add Singer</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <center><label style = "color: white; font-family:arial; font-size: 24px">Select a Regular</label></center>

<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","karaoke");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
  $sql = "Select * FROM regulars ORDER BY Regulars ASC";
  $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die("Bad SQL: $sql");
  $opt = "<select id = 'regulars' name = 'regulars'>";
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      $opt .= "<option value'{$row['Regulars']}'>{$row['Regulars']}</option>\n";
  }
 $opt .="</select>"
?>

<center> <div id="regulars">
<?php
echo $opt;
?>
</div> </center>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("regulars");
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = "Please Select";
    x.add(option, x[0]);
}
</sript>
myFunction()
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you have miss placed myFunction() outside of </script> and wrong <sript> instead of </script>

Comment: Instead of creating the "Please Select" option with Javascript, why not just put it before the `while` loop in PHP?

Comment: There are multiple errors. You're missing `=` for the `value`-attribute for your option tag. You have a typo: `</sript>` should be `</script>`. You have multiple elements with the same id `regulars`. You're calling the js function `myFunction()` after you're trying to close the script tag.

Answer (score 1):

You have a div tag with an id="regulars". This tag comes before you print out the $opt variable containing your select element which also has an id="regulars". The Javascript code is finding the first element with the "regulars" id which would be the div. Try changing the id of the div.

As mentioned in the comments, the *myFunction* function call should be in the *script* tags. The *option* tags should contain *=* for the *value* attribute.

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <html>
  <head>
  <title>Add Singer</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <center><label style = "color: white; font-family:arial; font-size: 24px">Select a Regular</label></center>

<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","karaoke");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
  $sql = "Select * FROM regulars ORDER BY Regulars ASC";
  $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die("Bad SQL: $sql");
  $opt = "<select id = 'regulars' name = 'regulars'>";
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      $opt .= "<option value='{$row['Regulars']}'>{$row['Regulars']}</option>\n";
  }
 $opt .="</select>"
?>

<center> <div id="regularsDiv">
<?php
echo $opt;
?>
</div> </center>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("regulars");
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = "Please Select";
    x.add(option, x[0]);
}
myFunction();
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```